# Heatmap Visualization Altair

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, heatmap, altair

I'm trying to visualize my data as a heatmap using the Altair library in python. I wasn't able to get the visualization to work with my own data, so I tried using a simple example, and it's still not visualizing correctly...

Any ideas what is wrong here?

```
import numpy.random as npr
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

random = npr.rand(4)
source = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y':[1,2,3,4], 'score':random})
alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x = alt.X('source.x:O'),
    y = alt.Y('source.y:O'),
    color = alt.Color('source.score:Q')
)
```

[See output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwcAB.png)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's just a typo in how you're referencing the columns, try this instead:

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x = alt.X('x:O'),
    y = alt.Y('y:O'),
    color = alt.Color('score:Q')
)
```